# Upgrading SOS-BERLIN Job scheduler on Linux x86-64 confusion

Tags: linux, job-scheduling

I am currently using [`Open Source Jobscheduler`](http://jobscheduler.sourceforge.net/) version 1.3.12.3137 installed through the file (`jobscheduler_linux.1.3.12.3137.tar.gz`).

Previously they have only two source files

```
jobscheduler_linux.1.3.12.3137.tar.gz
jobscheduler_windows.1.3.12.3137.zip
```

Where I used `jobscheduler_linux.1.3.12.3137.tar.gz`

Recently they have updated the installation sources and they have the following

```
jobscheduler_linux-x64.1.5.3253.tar.gz
jobscheduler_linux-x86.1.5.3253.tar.gz
jobscheduler_windows-x64.1.5.3253.zip
jobscheduler_windows-x86.1.5.3253.zip
```

My `uname -a` command says that it is [`x86_64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

`Linux openvas 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun May 6 04:00:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

So which one should I choose?

```
jobscheduler_linux-x64.1.5.3253.tar.gz
jobscheduler_linux-x86.1.5.3253.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Got the confirmation from SOS-BERLIN

Please choose `jobscheduler_linux-x64.1.5.3253.tar.gz`

To read more on compatibility read [here](http://www.sos-berlin.com/mediawiki/index.php/64-Bit_JobScheduler)

We can also update from 32 bit to 64 bit by unsing the update program and also have [64 bit instance Java Installed](http://www.sos-berlin.com/mediawiki/index.php/Z-JAVA-101_Java_Virtual_Machine_is_not_started).